# How do I debug renv::snapshot() which encounters an "Error in !deps$Dev : invalid argument type"?

Tags: renv

I have an R project that is using renv. However, I have neglected taking any snapshots for a while and I am now receiving cryptic messages that I don't know how to approach or even begin making a reporoducible example for. Any ideas, given that I am getting the following error message when I run `renv::status()`

```
> renv::status()
Error in !deps$Dev : invalid argument type
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In substring(u, so, so + ml - 1L) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
2: In substring(u, so, so + ml - 1L) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
Traceback (most recent calls last):
21: renv::status()
20: renv_status_impl(project, libpaths, lockpath, cache)
19: renv_status_check_missing_library(project, libpaths)
18: snapshot(project = project, library = libpaths, lockfile = NULL, 
        force = TRUE)
17: renv_lockfile_create(project, libpaths, type, packages)
16: renv_snapshot_r_packages(libpaths = libpaths, project = project) %>% 
        renv_snapshot_filter(project = project, type = type, packages = packages) %>% 
        renv_snapshot_fixup()
15: eval(call, envir = parent.frame())
14: eval(call, envir = parent.frame())
13: renv_snapshot_fixup(renv_snapshot_r_packages(libpaths = libpaths, 
        project = project) %>% renv_snapshot_filter(project = project, 
        type = type, packages = packages))
12: renv_snapshot_fixup_renv(records)
11: renv_snapshot_r_packages(libpaths = libpaths, project = project) %>% 
        renv_snapshot_filter(project = project, type = type, packages = packages)
10: eval(call, envir = parent.frame())
 9: eval(call, envir = parent.frame())
 8: renv_snapshot_filter(renv_snapshot_r_packages(libpaths = libpaths, 
        project = project), project = project, type = type, packages = packages)
 7: renv_snapshot_filter_implicit(project, records)
 6: renv_snapshot_filter_impl(project, records, project)
 5: renv_snapshot_dependencies(project, source)
 4: withCallingHandlers(dependencies(path = source, root = project, 
        progress = FALSE, errors = errors), renv.dependencies.error = renv_dependencies_error_handler(message, 
        errors))
 3: dependencies(path = source, root = project, progress = FALSE, 
        errors = errors)
 2: deps[!deps$Dev, ]
 1: `[.data.frame`(deps, !deps$Dev, )
```

which is the same message as when I run `renv::snapshot()`

```
> renv::snapshot()
Error in !deps$Dev : invalid argument type
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In substring(u, so, so + ml - 1L) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
2: In substring(u, so, so + ml - 1L) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
Traceback (most recent calls last):
18: renv::snapshot()
17: renv_lockfile_create(project, libpaths, type, packages)
16: renv_snapshot_r_packages(libpaths = libpaths, project = project) %>% 
        renv_snapshot_filter(project = project, type = type, packages = packages) %>% 
        renv_snapshot_fixup()
15: eval(call, envir = parent.frame())
14: eval(call, envir = parent.frame())
13: renv_snapshot_fixup(renv_snapshot_r_packages(libpaths = libpaths, 
        project = project) %>% renv_snapshot_filter(project = project, 
        type = type, packages = packages))
12: renv_snapshot_fixup_renv(records)
11: renv_snapshot_r_packages(libpaths = libpaths, project = project) %>% 
        renv_snapshot_filter(project = project, type = type, packages = packages)
10: eval(call, envir = parent.frame())
 9: eval(call, envir = parent.frame())
 8: renv_snapshot_filter(renv_snapshot_r_packages(libpaths = libpaths, 
        project = project), project = project, type = type, packages = packages)
 7: renv_snapshot_filter_implicit(project, records)
 6: renv_snapshot_filter_impl(project, records, project)
 5: renv_snapshot_dependencies(project, source)
 4: withCallingHandlers(dependencies(path = source, root = project, 
        progress = FALSE, errors = errors), renv.dependencies.error = renv_dependencies_error_handler(message, 
        errors))
 3: dependencies(path = source, root = project, progress = FALSE, 
        errors = errors)
 2: deps[!deps$Dev, ]
 1: `[.data.frame`(deps, !deps$Dev, )
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem solved itself after re-starting RStudio!